# Command ssh connection for 1000 linux servers

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, for

Please help me out from below situation.

There are 1000 linux servers with me. i need to find out which all servers are accepting passwordless connection from my master server. Below is the command i used. problem with below command is, when the destination server ask for password then my loop stop working.

```
for i in `cat srv`; do echo Server $i\n;  ssh $i "uptime"; done
```

Output:

```
Server server001

04:56:01 up 62 days,  9:18,  0 users,  load average: 0.09, 0.14, 0.13
```

Server server002

```
Password:
```

How can i resolve it.?

Comment: if you have that many servers, you should be using `pdsh` (parallel distributed shell)  or `clusterssh` or similar.   here's an intro article about them: [4 Useful Tools to Run Commands on Multiple Linux Servers](https://www.tecmint.com/run-commands-on-multiple-linux-servers/)

Comment: At 1000 servers you're well past the point where you should have set up something like `ansible` to manage the inventory a long time ago...

Answer (score 4):

try `-o BatchMode=yes` as `ssh` option.

This prevent password conformation in command line, as well as accepting remote host fingerprint.

You may wish to check return code from ssh

```
for host in $(< serverlist) 
do
  echo testing $host
  if ssh -o BatchMode=yes $host uptime
  then echo host $host OK
  else echo host $host KO
  fi
done > result.log
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you could do:

To find servers that do *not* accept passwordless login:

```
cat srv |
  parallel timeout 3 ssh {} true ' &>/dev/null ||' echo {}
```

To find servers that do accept passwordless login:

```
parallel --nonall --timeout 3 --slf srv --tag echo
```

Add `-j100` to run on 100 servers at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH options to specify you only want to use PubKey and not password authentication:

```
for i in `cat srv`; do echo Server $i\n;  ssh -o PubKeyAuthentication=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no $i "uptime"; done
```

This is outside the scope of this question, but you might want to check the return value of the `ssh` command to determine wether the connection succeeded or not.

Comment: Thank you panki. Suggested changes in the loop stops at the same place where destination server ask for the password, Do i need to add any wait command to skip the loop if it waits more than 5 seconds. Will that help ?

Comment: What do you mean? The remote server should not be asking for your password, but instead return `Permission denied (publickey,password).`